# How to display all numbers between a range, but every 3rd number is changed to an asterisk

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop, range

Just wondering how I do this, here is my code so far, but I can't seem to get it working, it shows all the numbers between 1-12 and adds the asterisk before the 3rd number, while still showing the 3rd number.

```
public class Help {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int i = 1;

    while(i < 12){
    System.out.println(i);
    i = i + 1;

    if(i % 3 == 0){
        System.out.println("*");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: rethink the logic, and use an `else`, so `if(i % 3 == 0){ System.out.println("*"); } else { System.out.println(i); }`. you probably should also use a for loop here because your i increment seems misplaced

Comment: use pen and paper analysis, or a debugger

Comment: `(i % 3 == 0)` may not be right test. Should range 2-8 list as `2 3 * 5 6 * 8` or `2 * 4 5 * 7 8` or `* 3 4 * 6 7 *`. All 3 examples follow the *"every 3rd number is changed to an asterisk"* requirement.

Comment: Yeah, (i % 3 == 0) isn't right for what I need, I've changed it to a for loop now, I'll try and figure out how to do every third number rather than every number divisible by 3, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want every third number to be count from the lower boundary of the range to display, then you cannot just use `number % 3 == 0`, because the "third" number changes depending on the lower boundary value, e.g. range 2-8 can be:

```java
2 * 4 5 * 7 8   // Using number % 3 == 0
2 3 * 5 6 * 8   // Counting from lower boundary
```

Here is a method for counting from lower boundary:

```java
private static void printRangeMask3(int from, int to) {
    for (int i = 0; i <= to - from; i++)
        System.out.println(i % 3 == 2 ? "*" : String.valueOf(from + i));
}
```

**Output** [IDEONE](https://ideone.com/Slw5hu)

```java
// printRangeMask3(1, 12)
1
2
*
4
5
*
7
8
*
10
11
*
```

```java
// printRangeMask3(2, 8)
2
3
*
5
6
*
8
```

Comment: thats more appropriate and generalised :)

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int hj=1;hj<12;hj++)
{
    if(hj%3==0)
    {
        System.out.println("*");
    }
    else
        System.out.println(hj);
}
```

hope my help works happy coding

Answer (score 0):

In your code above, the `System.out.println("*");` statement will be executed along with your `System.out.println("i");` statement. You only want ONE of these lines to run, so you should use an `else` statement like this:

```
while(i < 12){
    if(i % 3 == 0){
        System.out.println("*");
    } else {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
    i += 1; //same as i = i + 1;
}
```

This way, only one of these lines run, and every third number is replaced with an asterisk.

Answer (score 0):

You have a logic error in your code:
The test is carried out after the instruction is executed therefore you get an unexpected result.
If you are a beginner I would suggest you try and trace the code step by step to find out what's wrong or use a debugger.